# Como faço para adicionar uma coluna nova entre 2 colunas no PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Como eu faço para adicionar uma coluna nova entre duas colunas já existentes em minha base de dados no PostgreSQL?

No MySQL eu utilizo a função `AFTER` para adicionar uma coluna depois de uma outra, e no PostgreSQL? Como eu faço isso?

**SQL**

```
ALTER TABLE nota ADD hota_utc VARCHAR(2) AFTER hora_entrada_saida;
```

Comment: O `AFTER` é uma instrução somente do MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é possível. A solução é criar uma nova tabela com a nova estrutura com as colunas do jeito que você quer, copiar os dados para ela e depois de apagar a antiga, renomear a nova para tomar o lugar da antiga.

Em geral considera-se irrelevante a ordem das colunas.

Tem uma explicação de como proceder na [wiki do produto](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Alter_column_position).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ok @bigown. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Na verdade é possível, eu já pesquisei sobre o assunto em inglês, e achei respostas que mencionavam ser possível alterando os contadores internos no núcleo de gerecimento do postgres, em `information_schema` na tabela desejada, contudo o gerecimento para isto é tao grande que não é recomentado se fazer, além de em caso de erro poderia geraria complicações não só na tabela atual como em outras não desejadas. concluindo, é possível, mas é melhor fazer como o @bigown falou.

Comment: Não é possível de um jeito natural. Gambiarra sempre dá para fazer.

Comment: Atravessar a rua só para tentar escorregar numa casca de banana de outro lado ...